# How can I answer a question?

Tags: support

I was trying to solve the problem asked in [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52750121/css-grid-column-stretch-to-fill-entire-row-or-centered-in-row).

The answer that had been accepted didn't work for me, but I eventually an answer that worked for me.

I would like to add my answer to the original question to help other people like me who come across this question. However, I can't find the answer question button. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Welcome to Meta SE. The question you linked to has been closed as a duplicate, so nobody, including yourself, is allowed to provide a new answer to it. This is why there's no "Your Answer" section at the bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question has been marked as a duplicate of another question. This means that it will no longer accept any answers.

If you think you have a good answer, then look at the question it was marked a duplicate of: [Aligning grid items across the entire row/column (like flex items can)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50234112). If your answer is not one of the existing answers, then post your answer there instead—assuming it is applicable enough.

You will still be able to help other people when they find your answer in the other question, either directly or by being redirected to it from the one that was closed.